# Erro ao usar SimpleEmail

Tags: java

```
public void enviarEmail() throws EmailException{
    SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");//o servidor SMTP para envio do e-mail
    email.addTo("teste@gmail.com", "teste"); //destinatário
    email.setFrom("teste@gmail.com", "Me"); // remetente
    email.setSubject("Mensagem de Teste");// assunto do e-mail
    email.setMsg("Teste de Email utilizando commons-email"); //conteudo do e-mail
    email.send(); //envia o e-mail
}
```

Estou tentando fazer um código que envie um e-mail e esta dando o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/Authenticator

Comment: Quais `.jars` você possui no seu build path?

Comment: commons-email-1.5.jar
commons-email-1.5-javadoc.jar
commons-email-1.5-sources.jar
commons-email-1.5-tests.jar
commons-email-1.5-test-sources.jar

Comment: Vá ao link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7 e adicione a classe ao classpath.

Comment: Tente adicionar esse jar ao seu path: [activation.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar)

Comment: Adicionei esse .jar e esta dando este erro agora: "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25"

Comment: configura:
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=587
smtp.ssl=yes
smtp.user="me@gmail.com"
smtp.password="myPassword"

Comment: ou https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Ja foi adicionado e esta com o seguinte erro:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

Comment: Entao o melhor será abrir uma nova publicação, porque o erro de faltar a class está resolvido. Mais não sei porque apenas usei o google para responder as tuas dúvidas

Comment: Tenta setar a porta 587: `email.setSmtpPort(587)`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Adicione as seguintes dependências no pom.xml:**

```
   <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>     

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
```

**2. Crie um método para envio (preste atenção nos comentários):**

```
   public static void sendEmail() throws EmailException {

        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        // Utilize o hostname do seu provedor de email
        System.out.println("alterando hostname...");
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

        // Quando a porta utilizada não é a padrão (gmail = 465)
        email.setSmtpPort(465);

        // Adicione os destinatários
        email.addTo("karanalpe@hotmail.com");

        // Configure o seu email do qual enviará
        email.setFrom("karanalpe@gmail.com", "Karan User");

        // Adicione um assunto
        email.setSubject("Lembrete de senha");

        // Adicione a mensagem do email
        email.setMsg("Lembrete de senha karanalpe ");

        // Para autenticar no servidor é necessário chamar os dois métodos abaixo
        System.out.println("autenticando...");
        email.setSSL(true);
        email.setAuthentication("seuEmail@gmail.com", "suaSenha");
        System.out.println("enviando...");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("Email enviado!");
    }
```

**Referência:** http://karanalpe.com.br/tecnologia/back-end/enviando-email-com-o-java/

**Código fonte:**  https://github.com/karanalpe/envio-email